# How to make array 1*x and sum up its digits?

Tags: c, arrays, numbers, sum

So i have this type of problem. How to make an array 1*x and then sum up its digits together. I wrote down something like this for now. Any ideas? Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    int a,i,w,j,m;
    int s[a];
    printf("How many digits do you want to sum up\n");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    for(i=0;i<a;i++)
    {

        printf("Enter numer %d: ",i);
        scanf("%d",&s[i]);



    }
    for(j=0;j<a;j++)
        {
            m=s[j]+s[j++];
        }
    printf("\n %d",m);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `m = s[j] + s[j++]` its not corret. You should do something like `m = m + s[j]`.
Anyway i don't know if the rest of the code is correct, but for sure your sum was incorrect

Comment: So what exactly is your "type of problem"? Could you please more specific? Some remarks: You define `s[a]` before `a` has a meaningful value. Also, you don't really need an array, just the sum will do. But please _do_ initialise your variables. As it is, `m` can start off with any value.

Comment: Your question is imprecise: A number (which can have several digits)  is not the same thing as a digit. From your question it is unclear whether you want to add `x` numbers or `x` digits.

Comment: Yes, sorry i'm not native speaker i ment natural number where i wrote digit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems of your code are:

```
             int a;
             int s[a];
```

Here `a` is uninitialized.So,array size is unknown which is incorrect.And,instead of this

```
             m=s[j]+s[j++];
```

you should do like this :

```
             m  += s[j];
```

One more thing,you have initialize `m = 0` before starting to add.

I've Changed your program to this:

```
  #include <stdio.h> 

  int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

     int a,i,m = 0;

     //First get the array size
     printf("How many digits do you want to sum up\n");
     scanf("%d",&a);

     //Then declare the array with the size (a)
     int s[a];

     for(i = 0; i < a; i++){

       printf("Enter numer %d: ",i);
       scanf("%d",&s[i]);
       m += s[i];
    }

     printf("\n %d",m);

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: It's no chance for me to be any language developer right? Coz i have problems like that, which my colleagues are solving in split of a 10 minutes time.

Comment: No,It's nothing like that.These things happen for every single developers and everyone learns from mistakes.Without doing mistakes you can never be a developer of anything.

Comment: But i couldn't do it without your help, i think its something wrong, and i should not go in that direction of programing.

Comment: It's takes time to be efficient,don't be depressed.Every programmer has the same feeling at one stage,but everything will fine later when you have the basic.Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Using uninitialized variable is undefined behaviour.

```
int s[a];
```

The above statement defines an array `s` of size `a` but the value of `a` is unpredictable since it is uninitialized and contains garbage. The size of the array must be known when it defined and it remains the same throughout its lifetime. You cannot resize your array by changing the value of `a` here. You can use dynamic memory allocation using `malloc`.

Further, the following statement again invokes undefined behaviour -

```
m=s[j]+s[j++];
```

That's because it violates the the following rule stated in the C99 standard §6.5 ¶2

> Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its
>   stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression.
>   Furthermore, the prior value shall be read only to determine the value
>   to be stored.

Comment: I know that sum is not right coz as you wrote i don't have that j++ digit yet. But array works, the problem is with the sum, i don't know how to do it.

Comment: @1nterfector the array only appears to work but it's wrong. Like I mentioned, when the array is defined, its size must be known. At this time, the variable `a` contains garbage. You assign it after the array definition. This does not mean the array size will change accordingly. It remains fixed. And you don't know its size since `a` had unknown value at that point of time.